# Sum column until first empty cell

Tags: google-sheets, sum

i have the following table:

A1 - 25

A2 - 26

A3 - 27

A4 - BLANK

A5 - 30

A6 - 23

A7 - BLANK

A8 - 24

In B1, i want the following - Starting from A1, sum up the entries until the first blank cell is encountered. In this case, it would be 25+26+27 = 78.

I have looked at multiple answers for hours and tried tweaking them, but nothing is working. Any help is appreciated (Also many things do not make sense, the function isblank(a1:a10) is going to return true or false, then how does arrayformula(isblank(a1:a10)) suddenly convert it to an array, since isblank is just returning a boolean?)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way you can do it:

```
=sum(indirect("A1:A"&filter(row(A:A),A:A="")))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! since sheets lacks the dynamic array capability of Excel, filter will return the first result in the array.  Usually the array handling is a limitation, but nice way to turn it on its head and use it as an advantage!  That also means that the INDEX part of my second method is unnecessary.  I'm going to edit that part of the answer, thanks.

Comment: but it is still inferior to your construction (filtering the ROW() results directly).

Comment: FILTER() actually returns all the rows that match the condition but INDIRECT() only considers the first one (ie. the minimum).

Comment: Yes, filter returns an array, but in many cases Sheets handles arrays by just using the first value of the array, as opposed to Excel where the array will spill.  If you use filter as an argument for a function or in that concatenation there, it usually just uses the first value.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=FLATTEN(INDEX(QUERY(; "select "&SUBSTITUTE(JOIN("+"; 
 IF(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(ROW(A1:A)*(A1:A<>"")))=""; 
 ","; A1:A)); "+,+"; ",")); 2))
```

[image]

Comment: This formula was incredibly difficult to understand for me. Also ChatGPT was not able to explain it correctly and though it's broken.

The magic is the index() formula - index together with the range runs the loop.

The rest is simple parsing that generates a static string in the query select statement - in the end, the string comes down to something like "select 25+26+27,30+23,40,5+-6".

To understand better, the core part could be simplified as:
=index(if(A1:A11="",",",A1:A11))

Running this might very well blow your mind.

Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @pa1nd happy to explain next time

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of methods for it and a spreadsheet showing them both.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rkLarQC6NQ4HdGa38X3-rPoAW0A2-USvImFimlelhZM/edit#gid=0

Method 1: use MATCH to find the row of the first blank row, then construct a reference with INDIRECT to pass to SUM:

```
=sum(indirect("a1:a" & match("~~", arrayformula("~" & A1:A10 & "~"), 0) - 1))
```

Reformatted:

```
=sum(
  indirect(
    "a1:a" & 
    match(
      "~~", 
      arrayformula("~" & A1:A10 & "~"), 
      0
    ) - 1
  )
)
```

The only tricky thing here is that MATCH returns an error if you just pass it "" to look for, so I use ARRAYFORMULA to wrap the A1:A10 range in a delimiter (~ in this case, but that was arbitrary) and then look for ~~ in the array.  That returns me row 4, and so I use indirect to construct a reference to A1:A3 and pass that to sum.

---

***similar to ztiaa's method, but inferior.  He filters the ROW() results directly, and uses A:A as the filter argument.  Both are superior to my use of ISBLANK etc passed to FILTER***

Second, the same idea (find the number of the first empty row and construct a reference to pass to INDIRECT):

```
=sum(indirect("a1:a" & filter(ARRAYFORMULA(isblank(A2:A11)*row(A2:A11)), ARRAYFORMULA(isblank(A2:A11)*row(A2:A11))<>0)-1))
```

Reformatted for easier reading:

```
=sum(
  indirect(
    "a1:a" & 
    filter(
      ARRAYFORMULA(isblank(A1:A10)*row(A1:A10)), 
      ARRAYFORMULA(isblank(A1:A10)*row(A1:A10))<>0
    ) - 1, 
  )
)
```

So I use `ISBLANK(A1:A10)` to get an array of booleans indicating which rows are empty, then multiply that by `ROW(A1:A10)` which will return an array containing all the row numbers for the range, all inside of `ARRAYFORMULA`.

```
ARRAYFORMULA(isblank(A1:A10)*row(A1:A10))
```

Using boolean values in the multiplication converts them to zeroes, so this will generate an array of either 0 (for non-blank rows) or a row number (for any blank rows).  Then I take the same formula and use FILTER on it to remove all of the zeroes

```
      filter(
        ARRAYFORMULA(isblank(A1:A10)*row(A1:A10)), 
        ARRAYFORMULA(isblank(A1:A10)*row(A1:A10))<>0
      )
```

leaving an array containing the row numbers of each blank row.  Since they are in order and Sheets lacks dynamic array handling, the return value will just be the first value instead of the array, and so we can pass that to INDIRECT to generate a reference to a range using that row number - 1 (since I want to have the range run from A1 to the row immediately preceding the first blank row):

```
  indirect(
    "a1:a" & 
    filter(
      ARRAYFORMULA(isblank(A1:A10)*row(A1:A10)), 
      ARRAYFORMULA(isblank(A1:A10)*row(A1:A10))<>0
    )-1
  )
```

and then as a final step wrap the whole thing in SUM to sum the values in the range you just used INDIRECT to create a reference to.

```
=sum(
  indirect(
    "a1:a" & 
    filter(
      ARRAYFORMULA(isblank(A1:A10)*row(A1:A10)), 
      ARRAYFORMULA(isblank(A1:A10)*row(A1:A10))<>0
    )-1
  )
)
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Let me know if that works for you.  I imagine there is a better way to do it.  I'll keep thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Few alternative

```
=SUM(QUERY(A:A,"select A limit " & MIN(FILTER(ROW(A:A),A:A=""))-1))
```

With `INDEX()` function

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,min(filter(row(A:A),A:A=""))-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Query approach would be best for google-sheet.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, personally like the query approach but have accepted another formula since it is shorter.

Comment: @stebahpla No issue. Always best approach is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The answer from player0 is very interesting - but lacks explanation.
I could not find a single place in the internet (neither Google Docs, nor any other page) nor ChatGPT that can explain it, so I decided to create a more detailed explanation.

**Here the original formula:**

```
=FLATTEN(INDEX(QUERY(; "select "&SUBSTITUTE(JOIN("+"; 
IF(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(ROW(A1:A)*(A1:A<>"")))=""; 
","; A1:A)); "+,+"; ",")); 2))
```

**How it works:**

(1) The magic is the index() formula - index together with the range runs the loop.

(2) The rest is simple parsing that generates a static string in the query select statement - in the end, the string comes down to something like "select 25+26+27,30+23,40,5+-6".

**To understand index combined with a range and if:**

The most relevant part is:

```
=index(if(A1:A11="",",",A1:A))
```

Index causes the conditional to be executed line by line (just like `arrayformula()` would do it. So the loop iterates over every value from the condition, returns a comma if empty and otherwise the value.

The inner part of the query could be rewritten as:

```
"select "& 

SUBSTITUTE(
  JOIN(
    "+", 
    ARRAYFORMULA(
      IF(
        INDIRECT(
          "A1:A"&MAX(ROW(A1:A)*(A1:A<>""))
        )="", // INDIRECT: create range up to last not-empty cell
        ",",
        A1:A
      ) // IF: replace empty values in range with comma
    ), // ARRAYFORMULA: runs the loop
  ) // JOIN: create string out of range
"+,+", ",") // SUBSTITUTE: clean up string from empty lines
```

This might be very easy to understand by every advanced Google Sheet user.

Now note that:
(1) The `arrayformula()` could be replaced with a `index()` and it would yield the same result and
(2) The `arrayformula()` could be lifted outside of the query() and it would still yield the same result.